# Unable to record with extension Seraphic Web Security

Tags: security, jmeter

I have a problem with recording. It started after our organization installed Seraphic extension and I can't switch it off.
Is there a away to solve it without switch it off?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what "Seraphic extension" is but if it's a kind of proxy - you need to make JMeter aware of this upstream proxy as it's described in [Using JMeter behind a proxy](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#proxy_server) chapter of JMeter documentation.

You can also try out [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206732579-The-BlazeMeter-Chrome-Extension-Record-JMeter-Selenium-or-Synchronized-JMeter-and-Selenium) which makes recording process easier as you don't need to think of proxies and certificates.

And last but not the least you can record your test scenario using your [browser developer tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_are_browser_developer_tools), store the captured requests into a [HAR file](https://support.citrix.com/article/CTX275207/create-a-har-file-for-firefox) and [convert this HAR file into JMeter test script](https://converter.blazemeter.com/).

Comment: I have Blazemeter chrome extension but it disable, I can't enable it.
I guess the solution is in our company :)
Thanks DmitriT